# Parse Java source with Scala

Tags: java, parsing, scala

I am working on a static analysis tool and I need to work with Java source code and I'd like to write my code in Scala so that I can benefit from its functional features.

Is there any easy way to parse Java source code and have an Abstract Syntax Tree with Scala?
I thought at using some existing Java parsers written in Java but I wanted to make sure that I'm not missing some cool Scala library

Comment: Scala's parser combinator can be your choice

Comment: Is there any already implemented Java parser?

Comment: I would not say it will be _easy_ to create a tool for analyzing Java source code at a semantic level. There's far more to it than parsing, for one thing.

Comment: @RandallSchulz yes I know that. I am going to start with some simple analysis. I'd just like to avoid starting from scratch and get at least an AST, which would be enough to play with my simpler analysis.

Comment: The point is that an Abstract Syntax Tree is not purely syntactic. It cannot be built properly without creating a proper symbol table for program, and this is effectively a global analysis. With separate compilation, the information comes either from analyzing source files _or_ from `.class` files.

Comment: @RandallSchulz: Eh?  By definition ASTs are purely syntactic, and they are very easy to build *without* a symbol table (I build these for a living).    I agree that without a symbol table, there isn't a lot of interesting static analyses to do.    (Maybe you meant, "Abstract Syntax Graphs", which do require a symbol table to build).

Comment: If you want to accept huge amounts of non-Java (Java look-alike) code, perhaps.

Comment: @RandallSchulz: Eh?  A good *context* free parser will accept only things that look exactly like Java syntax (and can be used to build an AST; this is what parsing means colloquially).  Yes, such a parser will accept lots of invalid Java programs.  If you want something that will only accept valid Java programs as defined by the standard, you need not only symbol tables, but flow analysis and lots of other stuff, agreed.  If you want something that will accept only non-erroneous programs, you can't get it, you fall into the Turing tarpit, and that's why OP is interested in static analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I thought Scala could call Java libraries.

You should be able to call any Java-implemented Java parser (e.g., ANTLR).  That way you get a mature parser.

Comment: In doing a little background study on this question, I came across a Java analysis tool written with ANTLR. That would surely be a better starting point than a blank slate! It is described here: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/sandbox/trunk/jxr/maven-jxr/maven-jxr-java/src/site/resources/SeriesPt4.pdf

Comment: Yes, Scala can call Java libraries, as I reported in the question. I was just wondering if there is anything "better".